# Set git userName in IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I want to use git in IDEA. My computer has been used by my colleagues. Every time I push my code it, prompts me to enter the password. I had set
`git config --global user.userName ***` 
but in IDEA, the userName did not change.

I've been trying to solve the problem for three hours and it's not working. Is there a file where I can set my git userName in IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have mistyped the config key. It will be **user.name** not **user.userName**

And IDEA asking for a password because you have added HTTP(s) URL as your remote. You can change it with SSH URL and add your SSH-KEY in the Server.

To see all of your remotes

```
git remote -v
```

To delete one remote

```
git remote remove <REMOTE_NAME>
```

If your **REMOTE_NAME** is **origin** the command will be

```
git remote remove origin
```

To add a git URL as remote

```
git remote add <REMOTE_NAME> <URL>
```

if your **REMOTE_NAME** is **origin** and **URL** is **git@github.com:git/git.git** the command will be

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:git/git.git
```